# Colorbox function how to make image clickable

Tags: jquery, colorbox

New to jQuery so hope someone can help with something this basic: I found this great function for Colorbox provided by user3571366 and works perfectly.

```
<link href="popup/colorbox.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="popup/jquery.colorbox-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$.fn.colorbox({href:"popup/popup_image.jpg", open:true});
});
</script>
```

However, how do you make that popup_image.jpg clickable (ie. user clicks on the image to go a URL?)

Comment: Ok, so I just finished reading an article that you cannot append links to an image, but to a wrapper. Any ideas how to do this on this code? Thank you again!

Comment: isn't there any other html? can i see the anchor tag in which you have initialized the colorbox

Comment: No other html, that's pretty much it. It pops up as expected with no issues (it doesn't ask for anything in the <body> tag).

Comment: That's why it kind of throws me off and I can't find any documentation online on how to use a wrapper for the link...

Comment: you want only for one or it has to be dynamic?

Comment: Only for one static link to a page.

Answer (score 1):

For one static link you can use the below code

```
$.colorbox({
    href:"", 
    open:true,
    onComplete:function(){
        $('#cboxLoadedContent').click(function(){
            window.location.replace('http://www.google.com/');
        })
    }
});
```

for dynamic images, you can add a `data-url` value to the `anchor` links so that onclick it will dynamically redirect to that link.

**HTML**

```
<a class="group1" href="../content/ohoopee1.jpg" title="Me and my grandfather on the Ohoopee." data-url="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26623556/colorbox-function-how-to-make-image-clickable">Stackoverflow</a>
```

**JS**

```
$(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1',onComplete:function(e){
    if($(e.el).data('url'))
        $('#cboxLoadedContent').prop("onclick", null).unbind('click').click(function(){
                window.location.replace($(e.el).data('url'));
        })
}});
```

**UPDATE**

Replace your code with the below code.

```
$.colorbox({ 
    href:"http://s3.argim.net/files/s/gatobailedw7_4ew.gif", 
    open:true, 
    onComplete:function(){ 
        $('#cboxLoadedContent').click(function(){ 
            window.location.replace('http://google.com');
        }) 
    }
});
```

NOTE: DONOT forget to add `http://`

Comment: Thank you. But now the box stays on loading graphic with no pic showing. I really don't want to give up on Colorbox since it's a very clean approach to a lightbox but what do you think?

Comment: which solution have you used? the first one? did you forget to add the link in `href`?

Comment: Used the first one for static link. This is what I have:

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../js/jquery.colorbox-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$.colorbox({
    href:"http://s3.argim.net/files/s/gatobailedw7_4ew.gif", 
    open:true,
    onComplete:function(){
        $('#cboxLoadedContent').click(function(){
            window.location.replace('http://www.google.com');
        })
    }
});
</script>

Not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Can you put that in a fiddle and reproduce the same error??